# Twig and Assetic: images names in web directory

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

To display an image in my Twig template I do

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/mylogo.png'}}" />
```

It works fine if I put manually my image 'mylogo.png' in the 'web' directory of my application. But I don't think it is a good way to go. I should use the command 'assets:instal web'

The problem is when I use the command 'assets:instal web' the name of my image is modified (for example the name would be fce32_mylogo_2.png) . . . I think it is assetic who is modifying the name of my image.

But then my Twig template do not find my image when I use  to display that image.

Is it normal I put my image 'mylogo.png' manually in my web folder ?  I'm not sure about that . . .

Edit: I know I can use this synthax:

```
{% image 'bundles/myBundle/img/mylogo.png' %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
{% endimage %}
```

But this does not allow to pass twig variables. I would like to do this:

```
{% image 'bundles/myBundle/img/'~someVar.logoUrl %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
{% endimage %}
```

Answer (score 0):

clear your asset dumps and try this:

```
app/console assets:install web --symlink
```